# GridView loses data on postbacks when using DataPager

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate, datapager

I have a CustomGridView (extending GridView) and a DataPager and all works fine in .net 3.5 but not in .net 4. The problem is that when a postback occurs on pages other than the first the viewstate is lost for the grid. It's a large project and to make databinding occure on each postback is not an option because it's too much code to update (we started but we only created more bugs).

I have tested both the built in DataPager webcontrol and I have made my own with the same result. We know we should use built in pager for the grid but that solution is not possible because it's too much code to update.

The problem occurs on all pages that uses the CustomGridView and on gridpage 1 everything works fine

Is this a know problem and is there a workaround?

I give you code from a simple project with the same problem occuring (working in .net 3.5 but not .net 4):

WebForm1.aspx:

```
<cc1:SimpleCustomGridView ID="CustomGridView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="4" AllowPaging="true" 
        onpageindexchanging="CustomGridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        onrowcommand="CustomGridView1_RowCommand" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Visible="true">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="lnkClick" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </cc1:SimpleCustomGridView>
    <br />
    <uc:DataPager ID="DataPager" runat="server" CustomGridViewID="CustomGridView1" />
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBind(0);
    }
}

private void DataBind(int pageIndex)
{
    int rowIndex = pageIndex * CustomGridView1.PageSize;
    int pageSize = CustomGridView1.PageSize;
    int total;
    List<DataContainer> list = DataContainer.GetData(rowIndex, pageSize, out total);
    CustomGridView1.RowCount = total;
    CustomGridView1.DataSource = list;
    CustomGridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void CustomGridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewPageIndex > -1)
    {
        CustomGridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        DataBind(e.NewPageIndex);
    }
}

protected void CustomGridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) { }
```

SimpleCustomGridView.cs:

```
public class SimpleCustomGridView : GridView
{
    public override int PageIndex
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState[this.ClientID + "PAGEINDEX"] == null)
                ViewState[this.ClientID + "PAGEINDEX"] = 0;
            return (int)ViewState[this.ClientID + "PAGEINDEX"];
        }
        set
        {
            base.PageIndex = value;
            ViewState[this.ClientID + "PAGEINDEX"] = value;
        }
    }

    public int RowCount
    {
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[this.ClientID + "TOTALPAGECOUNT"] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[this.ClientID + "TOTALPAGECOUNT"] == null ? 0 :
                Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session[this.ClientID + "TOTALPAGECOUNT"]);
        }
    }

    public void GotoPage(int pageIndex)
    {
        GridViewPageEventArgs args = new GridViewPageEventArgs(pageIndex);
        OnPageIndexChanging(args);
    }
}
```

CustomGridViewpager.ascx.cs:

```
public partial class CustomGridViewpager : UserControl
{
    public string CustomGridViewID { get; set; }

    private SimpleCustomGridView _gridView;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        _gridView = (SimpleCustomGridView)Parent.FindControl(CustomGridViewID);
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        int totalRows = _gridView.RowCount;
        int pageIndex = _gridView.PageIndex;
        int pageSize = _gridView.PageSize;
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRows / (double)pageSize);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(pageIndex + 1);
        sb.Append("/");
        sb.Append(totalPages);
        PageIndexLabel.Text = sb.ToString();

        PrevPageButton.Visible = pageIndex > 0;
        NextPageButton.Visible = pageIndex < totalPages - 1;

    }

    protected void NextPageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _gridView.GotoPage(_gridView.PageIndex + 1);

    }

    protected void PrevPageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _gridView.GotoPage(_gridView.PageIndex - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: while working in NET4.0, did you get any error message? JS console message?

Answer (score 0):

Try put the `DataBind(0);` inside the `OnPreRender()` method of the webform

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    DataBind(0);
}
```